# SQL Many-to-Many Composite Key Link Table Join

Tags: sql, join, many-to-many

I hope this is not a duplicate of a question, but I have three tables I'm trying to pull information from.

My table's schemas look like so:

### Computers

ComputerID (PK)
CreatedDateTime
FriendlyName
ComputerName

### EventEntries

EventEntryID
EventEntrySource (These two form the PK)

### Link_Computers_EventEntries

EventEntryID EventEntrySource ComputerID

All I want to do is pull a list of event entries--their EventEntryID & EventEntrySource from the link table depending on which ComputerID my query specifies.

I believe this should be simple but I am not a SQL expert.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query produces the intended result:

```
SELECT EventEntryID, EventEntrySource 
FROM Link_Computers_EventEntries
WHERE ComputerID=1 -- Where 1 represents the "specified" ComputerID value
```

Comment: Sorry I was incorrect.  It is a many-to-many there is no foreign key on the event entries table pointing to a computer ID.  This is because many computers can have many of the event entries listed in the event entries table.

Comment: OK, so was AtomID intended to be ComputerID, then?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.  I've editied and made that change as well.